# What does the "code unit value" mean in ECMA-262 (JavaScript 5 edition)?

Tags: javascript

I'm watching ECMA-262 (JavaScript 5 edition) and cannot understand what is "code unit value"?

Can anyone tell me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you add some context, like the paragraph it is mentioned in?

Comment: Pekka, thank you for your reply! The question has been answered by Mathias Bynens at below. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JavaScript string is a sequence of unsigned 16-bit integers, also known as *code units*.

A *code point* is how the Unicode standard represents symbols and non-symbols. Code points are represented as a four-to-six digit hexadecimal number, typically prefixed with `U+`, e.g. U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A.

The difference is that what can be part of a code unit depends on the character encoding that is used. A code point however, is merely the concept of a “character” that can then potentially be encoded using UTF-8, for example.

For more information, read [chapter 2 of the Unicode spec](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch02.pdf#G25564), especially *2.4 Code points and characters*.

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-6 defines the terms "code unit" and "code point" as two separate concepts, the former being limited to characters which can be represented by 16 bits and the latter referring to a Unicode scalar value.