# Javascript Regular Expressions Character Range A-z Matches Caret ("^")

Tags: javascript, regex

From the Chrome console, I noticed this oddity:

```
/[^A-z]/.test("^")
false
/[A-z]/.test("^")
true

"^".charCodeAt(0)
94
"A".charCodeAt(0)
65
"z".charCodeAt(0)
122

/[a-zA-Z]/.test("^")
false
```

It would make sense that caret matches in the range of 65-122 since it's character code is 94, but I didn't realize that /[A-z]/ is not equivalent to /[a-zA-Z]/.

So I guess my question is, does javascript use ASCII codes for ranged matches like A-z? And is that the explanation for this behavior?

EDIT:

After some further investigation, this appears to be true

```
String.fromCharCode(91)
"["
String.fromCharCode(92)
"\"
String.fromCharCode(93)
"]"
String.fromCharCode(94)
"^"
String.fromCharCode(95)
"_"
String.fromCharCode(96)
"`"

/[^A-z]/.test("^[\\_`")
false
```

Comment: Actually, it uses [Unicode](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset), not ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ECMAScript 15.10.2.15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.15) handles the generation of range-based character sets during regular expression evaluation. When building a range from character `A` to character `B` (i.e., `A-B`):

> 1. Let *a* be the one character in *CharSet A*.
> 2. Let *b* be the one character in *CharSet B*.
> 3. Let *i* be the **code unit value** of character *a*.
> 4. Let *j* be the **code unit value** of character *b*.
> 5. If *i* > *j* then throw a SyntaxError exception.
> 6. Return the set containing all characters numbered *i* through *j*, inclusive.

The phrase "code unit value" here [is a Unicode term](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5244664/710446). Thus, the range `A-z` includes all characters whose Unicode code unit values fall between the code unit values of `A` and `z`, inclusive. This range (`0x41` - `0x7A`) does include [six non-alphabetic characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65&number=128):

```
U+005B  [   5b  LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
U+005C  \   5c  REVERSE SOLIDUS
U+005D  ]   5d  RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
U+005E  ^   5e  CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
U+005F  _   5f  LOW LINE
U+0060  `   60  GRAVE ACCENT
```

Answer (score 3):

`/[A-z]/` range means code range from 65 to 122 and that includes 94 as well which is `^`

That's the reason `/[A-z]/` will match `^` OR `[` OR `]` OR `_` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in regex, the caret means the start of a new line. You have to escape it with a backslash if you mean the literal caret character.

However, anubhava's answer above is the reason you are seeing this behavior.

Comment: As the first character inside `[]`, the caret means to negate the matching of the block, not the start of a new line.